# VSTS Query for User Stories with no linked code

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am trying to come up with a query in VSTS for user stories that don't have any associated code (no linked branch or no linked commits). Is this possible? I don't see how to query for child links that are not work items. I am using a git repository and have stories in the current sprint with linked branches. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

work item query can not achieve it (only list user stories which are not link with branch/commit).

But you can use REST API to achieve it. Details as below:

#### 1.   [List work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1#uri-parameters) you want to check

You can list the work items as below:

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems?ids={ids}& $expand=all&api-version=4.1
```

#### 2.   Filter the list work items which are not link with branch/commit

Then filter the work items by `ArtifactLink` url. If the URL start with `vstfs:///Git/Ref` or `vstfs:///Git/Commit`, that means the work item link with branch/commit.

Such as work item link a branch:

```
"relations": [
    {
        "rel": "ArtifactLink",
        "url": "vstfs:///Git/Ref/5e24b6e0-5832-4d9f-addf-a293ef8874d8%2F20d85f1a-7145-42ea-b7c6-800f68e8dd2c%2FGBb1",
        "attributes": {
            "authorizedDate": "2018-07-26T07:55:35.723Z",
            "id": 1146190,
            "resourceCreatedDate": "2018-07-26T07:55:35.723Z",
            "resourceModifiedDate": "2018-07-26T07:55:35.723Z",
            "revisedDate": "9999-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "name": "Branch"
        }
    }
]
```

And work item link a commit:

```
"relations": [

    {
        "rel": "ArtifactLink",
        "url": "vstfs:///Git/Commit/5e24b6e0-5832-4d9f-addf-a293ef8874d8%2F20d85f1a-7145-42ea-b7c6-800f68e8dd2c%2F943a42193ea963f8717c3901542f2b3d48ad8dfc",
        "attributes": {
            "authorizedDate": "2018-07-26T07:14:33.91Z",
            "id": 1146154,
            "resourceCreatedDate": "2018-07-26T07:14:33.91Z",
            "resourceModifiedDate": "2018-07-26T07:14:33.91Z",
            "revisedDate": "9999-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "name": "Fixed in Commit"
        }
    }
]
```